where is the TLS session key stored when configuring nginx ssl engine as pkcs11?
I configure ssl_engine in nginx as pkcs11. It means that nginx server used the key stored in hsm as its identity in TLS connection. However, the TLS master key (or shared key, or session key) is depend on what comes from client, cannot be generated in hsm itself.
So are those key : the TLS master key (and shared key, and session key) stored in nginx memory instead of HSM? if yes, the incoming TLS traffic to nginx are not decrypted in HSM, are they?
Thank you!

"How can TLS traffic be forced to decrypt inside an HSM?" - why do you want this? It would be terribly slow. And yes, HSM is only used for the private key of the certificate, not for the (comparably short lived) key material specific for the current TLS session.
